# How do I make this function automatic, it clearly has a pattern

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, data-structures, recursive-datastructures

```py
def populate_kids(self, arr, used_Indices):
    for a in self.children:
        a.get_all_jumps(arr, used_Indices)

    for a in self.children:
        for b in a.children:
            b.get_all_jumps(arr, used_Indices)

    for a in self.children:
        for b in a.children:
            for c in b.children:
                c.get_all_jumps(arr, used_Indices)

    for a in self.children:
        for b in a.children:
            for c in b.children:
                for d in c.children:
                    d.get_all_jumps(arr, used_Indices)
```

How do I make this automatically

I tried recursion it doesn't seem to work

Comment: What do you mean by automatic? From seeing the code you can make this function a single for loop by using the last for loop and adding the rest of the code from the other loops into one.

Comment: I'm guessing it's important to do all the top-level children first (i.e. breadth-first)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a BFS (breadth-first-search), so something along these lines might work:

```
def populate_kids(self, arr, used_Indices):
    queue = self.children
    while queue:
        next_queue = []
        for a in queue:
            a.get_all_jumps(arr, used_Indices)
            if a.children:
                next_queue.extend(a.children)
        queue = next_queue
```

The basic idea is that as you process the queue, you add the next level of items to search to the queue for the next iteration.  Eventually you reach the point where there are no more levels, and the search ends.

For a DFS (depth-first search), recursion is easier (I'm assuming the objects in `self.children` have the same type as `self`):

```
def populate_kids(self, arr, used_Indices):
    for a in self.children:
        a.get_all_jumps(arr, used_Indices)
        a.populate_kids(arr, used_Indices)
```

but the order of traversal will be different (you'll recurse all the way down to the deepest level before finishing the loop at the current level).

Answer (score 0):

Use **recursion** to automate a function that populates data in a tree-like structure. By defining a recursive function that calls itself on each child of a node, the function can handle any pattern of nested children, eliminating the need for repetitive for loops. In this way, all descendants of a node can be processed without explicitly iterating through each level.

```
    def populate_kids(self, arr, used_Indices):
            for child in self.children:
                self._populate_kids_recursive(child, arr, used_Indices)
        
        def _populate_kids_recursive(self, node, arr, used_Indices):
            node.get_all_jumps(arr, used_Indices)
            for child in node.children:
                self._populate_kids_recursive(child, arr, used_Indices)
```